# How to add user input to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Ask the user for a string and creates the following dictionary: The values are the letters in the string, with the corresponding key being the place in the string. For example if the user entered the string `CSC120` then  create the dictionary `d`.

```
d = { 0:'C', 1:'S', 2:'C', 3:'1', 4:'2', 5:'0'}
```

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Please show an effort to solve this yourself.

Comment: x = 0
s = 0
students = []
while x < 2:
    x += 1
    name  = input("please enter a name> ")
    s += 1
    student = {}
    student['name'] = name
    student['s'] = s
    students.append(student)
print(students)

Comment: Please add the code to your post.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `dict` function on the result of `enumerate`:

```
s = "CSC120"
result = dict(enumerate(s))
print(result)
# {0: 'C', 1: 'S', 2: 'C', 3: '1', 4: '2', 5: '0'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
userStr=input("please enter a word") # asking the user to enter a string

d={} # initialize an empty dictionary "d"

# looping through the value of userStr by each index of letter in userStr # and the letter itself.
for i,letter in enumerate(userStr): 
    d[i]=letter # adding a key and value in the dictionary "d"

print(d)    # printing the dictionary "d"
```

Comment: Even though this may answer the question, there is no explanation of your code. Please update your answer to provide an explanation of what you are doing. Thanks!